# Error occuring on some Android devices involving GSON

Tags: android, gson

The problem appears to happen only on Samsung devices. However it did happen on one non Samsung device. I've been trying to replicate the issue on my phone (Nexus 5, vanilla lollipop) but it doesn't happen.

This saves an ArrayList of an ArrayList of an ArrayList of BusEntrys

```
private static void saveDataList(ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<BusEntry>>> list, String key1){
    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(RO.mainActivity.getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<BusEntry>>> entries = list;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonEntries = gson.toJson(entries);
    //Log.d("TAG", "jsonCars = " + jsonEntries);
    prefsEditor.putString(key1, jsonEntries);
    prefsEditor.commit();

}
```

This loads an ArrayList of an ArrayList of an ArrayList of BusEntrys

```
private static Object getDataList(String key, int task){
    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(RO.mainActivity.getApplicationContext());
    String jsonString = appSharedPrefs.getString(key, ""); // TODO use empty string as an if statement to determine if you need to recache
    Type type;
    type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<BusEntry>>>>(){}.getType();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
}
```

Error Stack

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.joltimate.umdshuttle/com.joltimate.umdshuttle.MainActivity}: com.google.a.aa: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 7 path $[0].b
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by: com.google.a.aa: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 7 path $[0].b
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read()
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write()
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read()
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read()
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read()
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read()
   at com.google.gson.Gson.doubleAdapter()
   at com.google.gson.Gson.doubleAdapter()
   at com.google.gson.Gson.doubleAdapter()
   at com.joltimate.umdshuttle.Data.DataStorage.saveDataList()
   at com.joltimate.umdshuttle.Data.DataStorage.getAllData()
   at com.joltimate.umdshuttle.Data.DataStorage.saveDataList()
   at com.joltimate.umdshuttle.MainActivity.onCreate()
```

Comment: Can you post the code how you called DataStorage.saveDataList(), DataStorage.getAllData()?

Comment: did it happen on more than one samsung devices? what is the Android o.s. version in nexus and samsung ?

Comment: @user2450263 it's happening on multiple Samsung devices as well as HTC devices. I haven't gotten it to happen on my Nexus 5 though.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
Type type;
type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<BusEntry>>>>(){}.getType();
Gson gson = new Gson();
return gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

From the [documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
int[] ints = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

(Serialization)
gson.toJson(ints);     ==> prints [1,2,3,4,5]

(Deserialization)
int[] ints2 = gson.fromJson("[1,2,3,4,5]", int[].class); 
==> ints2 will be same as ints
```

It would seem you are not returning the expected type.

I would suggest something like the following:

```
class SpecialArrayType{

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<BusEntry>> specialArrayType;
    public void setSpecialArrayType(ArrayList<ArrayList<BusEntry>> list){
        this.specialArrayType = list;
    }

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<BusEntry>> getSpecialArrayType(){
        return specialArrayType;
    }

}

// Get the array list as a special type, then deal with the nested lists.

ArrayList<SpecialArrayType> lists = new ArrayList<SpecialArrayType>();
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<SpecialArrayType>>(){}.getType();
Gson gson = new Gson();
lists = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);

ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<BusEntry>>> returnList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<BusEntry>>>();

// Loop through special array list to populate info from nested array lists.
for(SpecialArrayType list1: lists){

    // We have these items in our outer array list, we want to add them to our
    // return list.
    returnList.Add(list1);

    // The next nested array list.
    list1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BusEntry>>();

    for(ArrayList<BusEntry> list2: list1){
        // Populate each specialArrayType with an array list of array list of BusEntries.
        list1.Add(list2);
        // Find each nested array list of bus entries.
        list2= new ArrayList<BusEntry>> ();

        for(BusEntry entry: list2){
            list2.Add(entry);
        }
    }

}       

return returnList;
```

So you are returning the fully nested data.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I'm not 100% sure yet, but I believe the problem was actually nothing in my code. I think the issue was that I was originally storing the json as Arrays and then changed it to ArrayLists in a new version. So when people upgraded to a new version of the app it was expecting ArrayLists when it the json being stored was Arrays.

Comment: So what I said in the previous comment to have fixed the problem. I'm going to award you the 50 points anyway because something about what you said made me realize the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Add following library in your android studio project instead of putting manual library in library folder.

```
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

and if you are trying to store arraylist or class object in sharedpreferences using GSON then try this tutorial : [click here](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/sharedpreference/)